# Thinktecture Implicit Flow with External Identity Providers (facebook, google, adfs etc...)

Tags: oauth, thinktecture-ident-server

I can't seem to figure this out.

Is there any possible way to choose an identity provider to login when using the implicit flow of the oauth2 method used here? I can't seem to have anything besides the web identities login.

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/11/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-implicit-grant-flow-with-javascript.html

and here?

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/06/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-using-the-implicit-flow-with-windows-store-clients/

I'd like something similar to the home realm discovery for logging on, unfortunately I'm not sure whether this is a limitation of the protocol, framework, or it's really just something I have to implement myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federation is only supported for WS-Federation right now.

Comment: Ah thank you so much for such a quick response! I praise the work you're doing. I'm learning so much from it.